# build android system on ubuntu 10.04 x86-64 occrur internal compiler error

Tags: android

I'm trying to build android system ;
enviroment: ubuntu 10.04, gcc-4.4 jdk 1.6-0-20
get source code follows http://source.android.com/source/download.html

$ . build/envsetup.sh

$ choosecombo

$ make

then compiler error occurs:

frameworks/base/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp:1955:   instantiated from here
frameworks/base/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp:72: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
frameworks/base/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp:74: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

**frameworks/base/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp: In member function ‘virtual EGLBoolean android::egl_window_surface_v2_t::swapBuffers()’:
frameworks/base/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp:554: internal compiler error: in add_phi_arg, at tree-phinodes.c:391**

in line 554: the code below:
const Region copyBack(Region::subtract(oldDirtyRegion, dirtyRegion));

Any one know the solution ? 
roll back to gcc4.3 may not a nice solution

Answer (score 1):

try to remove const from the line below

> const Region
>   copyBack(Region::subtract(oldDirtyRegion,
>   dirtyRegion))